# Report translation sales order/ quotation not working

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

I have added this code to the sale module

```
sale -> i18n -> nl.po
```

but it's not translated in the report/pdf file

```
#. module: sale
#: report:sale.order:0
msgid "Disc.(%)"
msgstr "Krt. (%)"

#. module: sale
#: view:sale.report:0
#: field:sale.report,price_total:0
msgid "Total"
msgstr "Totaalprijs"

#. module: sale  
#: field:sale.advance.payment.inv,qtty:0
#: report:sale.order:0
#: field:sale.order.line,product_uom_qty:0
msgid "Quantity"
msgstr "Hoeveelheid"
```

Comment: did you reload the language in openerp? sometimes the languages aren't reloaded/installed properly after module update

Comment: i also reload language but it's not working in report

Comment: is nothing translated or only these three examples (in report) ?

Comment: Hi Atul, Did you find any answer for that? I am facing the same isseu.